# PHPExcel and mPDF Giving me set Rendername and Path errors

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have the newest version of PHPExcel.

From what I understand I dont need to download mPDF because its already inside PHPExcel, Correct?

Everytime I try to run this though it tells me this error

> NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values
>   at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure

Which does not make any sense to me because I have set the paths to exactly what they are. Am I missing anything?

Here is the full code.

```
                    <?php
                include_once 'processor/dbconfig.php';

                /**
                 * PHPExcel
                 *
                 * Copyright (C) 2006 - 2014 PHPExcel
                 *
                 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
                 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
                 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
                 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
                 *
                 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
                 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
                 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
                 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
                 *
                 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
                 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
                 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
                 *
                 * @category   PHPExcel
                 * @package    PHPExcel
                 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006 - 2014 PHPExcel (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)
                 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt    LGPL
                 * @version    1.8.0, 2014-03-02
                 */

                /** Error reporting */
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
                ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
                date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

                if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
                    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

                /** Include PHPExcel */
                require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';


                //  Change these values to select the Rendering library that you wish to use
                //      and its directory location on your server
                //$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
                $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
                //$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
                //$rendererLibrary = 'tcPDF5.9';
                $rendererLibrary = 'mPDF.php';
                //$rendererLibrary = 'domPDF0.6.0beta3';
                $rendererLibraryPath = 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF' . $rendererLibrary;


                // Create new PHPExcel object
                $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

                // Set document properties
                $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                             ->setTitle("PDF Test Document")
                                             ->setSubject("PDF Test Document")
                                             ->setDescription("Test document for PDF, generated using PHP classes.")
                                             ->setKeywords("pdf php")
                                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


                // Add some data
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
                            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
                            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
                            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

                // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
                            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

                // Rename worksheet
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridLines(false);

                // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


                if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
                        $rendererName,
                        $rendererLibraryPath
                    )) {
                    die(
                        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                        '<br />' .
                        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
                    );
                }


                // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (PDF)
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.pdf"');
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
                $objWriter->save('php://output');
                exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

No! You've set the path so that they point to PHPExcel's ***wrapper*** for mPDF.... this is meaningless, because PHPExcel already knows where its PDF wrappers are. What it doesn't know is where you have installed mPDF..... that's what you should be telling PHPExcel with these settings.

Comment: So I downloaded mPDF...  I dragged the whole folder into Classes and named in mpdf... Now in my directories I have library path as Classes/mpdf and Library as mpdf.php  Now when I run it.. it downloads but when I open it.. in acrobat is says its corrupted and cannot open.. When I try and open with Chrome it says it cannot open this file.

Comment: Then check for error messages in the logs, or in the generated file..... if you're testing using a download (it's far better to test by generating the file on the server) then any error messages are injected directly into that file and will corrupt it.... likewise any output that you generate yourself (deliberately via echo/print, or accidentally outside of `?>` tags)